# Show on PivotChart... sum of two fields

Tags: excel, math

OK, let's say I have this `PivotChart`:

[image]

I have a **[excel sheet of football matches](http://puu.sh/6leOt.png)** and I watch to see the highest scoring team but it only does either home or away and I want to combine the two... how can I do that on my `PivotChart` fields? [image]

Comment: what do you mean `I want to combine the two`? as in like a stackbar?

Comment: @L42 Well yes... combine the away and home score because for example Team A may have scored 3 goals in one home where they were `home` but in an `away` game, Team A scored 6 goals... thus I want to add upp both home and away score. Does that make sense?

Comment: Just FYI - This question seems more appropriate for Super User (another StackExchange site). You might want to ask there.

Comment: you need to add q calculated field to the pivot table [link](http://m.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-add-calculated-fields-to-pivot-tables-in-ex.html) or using a stacked column chart would have a similar affect

Comment: then just change the chart type. Right click on the chart and you'll see it. choose `Stack Column`.

Comment: I see the Pivot ribbon but not the Tools -> Formula part...

Comment: @pnuts I misinterpreted the question, my previous comment is withdrawn. For the OP, I would create a new data structure to support the reporting/charting. Have one row per team, then either sum up the home scores & away scores in separate columns (if you want to create a stacked bar chart), or just the total of home+away scores. In either case the pivot table & chart seem like unnecessary headaches, YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest inserting a column immediately to the right of B say labelled GSum with:

```
=SUMIF(F:F,B2,E:E)+SUMIF(B:B,B2,D:D)
```

in C2 and copied down to suit. In the PT add a Calculated Field, say `Goals` with `=SUM(GSum)/2` and Sum of Goals at the bottom of Σ Values.

With luck on refresh the results might be similar to shown in this simplified example:

[image: SO21126973 example]

Note that, for example, `C` has not scored at home (so no blue) but has had three goals scored against it at home (brown). You might prefer the latter to indicate how many goals `C` has scored away (ie 4 - the same as it has scored in total) instead.